# Servlet getParts empty from php proxy and not directly from myform

Tags: java, php, proxy, httprequest, servlet-3.0

As I said in https://stackoverflow.com/q/35060446/487313 I'm working on a php proxy.Actually I have a servlet with the annotation:

```
@MultipartConfig
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Further in the doPost I have:

```
  Collection<Part> lesParts = request.getParts();
```

And strangely I always get an empty Collection when coming through my proxy and the right thing when comming directly from my form
That is to say:
`<form name="mon-formulaire1" id="proxyform" action="newPrxi.php?proxy_url=http://localhost:8888/testServlet/myservlet.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >` doesn't work
and 
`<form name="mon-formulaire1" id="proxyform" action="http://localhost:8888/testServlet/myservlet.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >` is ok.
Actually I'm working on my localhost with php on Vstudio(port 30645) and the servlet on Tomcat 7 under Eclipse (port 8888).
I used `request.getInputStream();` and iterating through the headers with `Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();` AND I can't see no difference between the case which is ok (direct from form) and the one which is ng (through the proxy). All this code is normally commented to avoid to have an empty request after reading the stream....
My form got two input text and two file input elements, it doesn't change anything when I uplpoad a file or not (the file is well saved when the part list is not empty).
My headers are the followings:

```
Key: content-type, Value: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHEJ3XuT0gdC8RG4X
Key: connection, Value: keep-alive
Key: accept-language, Value: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Key: host, Value: localhost:8888
Key: accept, Value: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Key: content-length, Value: 105639
Key: origin, Value: http://localhost:30645
Key: user-agent, Value: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
Key: accept-encoding, Value: gzip, deflate
Key: referer, Value: http://localhost:30645/index.html?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=76F0F204
```

ANy help would be more than welcome.... :)

Comment: I would save the headers and the request body in both cases (proxy, non-proxy) and do a byte-wise comparison of both outputs to be sure that there is no difference

Comment: Your comment encourage me to reverify more closely and I found I forgot to add the two -- as a prefix to each boundary. So It's still not working but now there should be something else. You can copy your comment as  an answer if you wnt me to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the servlet cannot return the parts of a multipart request when running behind a proxy, the most likely explanation is that the proxy added or removed stuff which makes the request incorrect or unparsable.

As detected in the comment conversation this was actually the case.

Comment: My problem was that I was not accurate enough in my comparaison (starting from something like "I can't be wrong".. stupid) and I was missing also the two -- at the end of the closing boundary. MY BAD. Thanks for giving me the right kick